# What is a good introductory book on plant genetics for an outsider?

Tags: genetics, book-recommendation

I am interested in plant breeding, but my knowledge about plant genetics itself is unfortunately limited (math major). Would you know of any good introductory '101' books that explain the basic concepts? As elementary as: what exactly is DNA recombination? What is an F1, F2 plant?

Many thanks and kind regards,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in a PSEO class for plant biology and ecology and I found a book online I believe you would find useful.

Click [here](https://t.alibris.com/Plant-Biotechnology-and-Genetics-Principles-Techniques-and-Applications/book/28445906)

I've used this book to study many times even though it wasn't supplied to me. It does a great job explaining overall concept of plant microbiology. This book will introduce concepts that someone would be new to. I recommend that you give it a read, then after you read it, move to a book specifically on plant breeding.

Hope this helped!

-Sartoaster